# Azure WebService Deployment from GitHub fails

Tags: azure, deployment, github

All of a sudden I have problems with the automatic deployment from GitHub to my WebService (free) in Azure.

The deploy fails and when I look in the log thisa is what is says:

```
Command 'git.exe fetch external  ...' aborted due to no output and CPU activity for 60 seconds.  You may increase SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT setting to solve the issue.
git.exe fetch external --progress
```

This seems to be internal to Azure and I am wondering if anyonelse have seen this?

Comment: Sometimes the GitHub app will give you more info.  I'd install the GitHub app (for Windows or Mac).  Clone the repo, then try a commit and sync.  See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use the GitHub app but in this case it wouldn't help since it is the Azure Web Service server that is talking to GitHub.

Comment: Could it be related to SSL certificates? I had that problem when autodeploying from TFS Online after leaving the site for a few months, and all I needed was to set up the connection from scratch again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 1/3/2015:** it appears that this issue is triggered, by turning on the Virtual Network (vnet) feature on the Azure Website. We're still investigating why this happens, but at least we know it's not random.

**Original answer:**

Seems the git fetch is hanging for some reason. It could happen if it's prompting for creds, but there may be other reasons.

I'd suggest using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to manually run git commands in your site\repository folder on Azure, to try to isolate the issue outside of a full deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the Kudu console. I didn't know about that! (Shows my ignorance I guess... :-) Will take deep dive!

Comment: Any suggestions if the commands just hangs when running them in the kudu console?

Comment: Depends what's the command that's hanging. The best guess is that it's prompting for input, which you want to avoid.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, ok, is there a way to figure out what it's waiting for? It did work before and I didn't do any changes that I know of.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, it doesn't seem like it's waiting for input. I've tried it in the Kudu Console as well, and it just hangs there as well. It works if I push the code manually from my machine to azure.

Comment: Kudu console is not always able to show input, as it's not a 'real' console. One possible approach: download a dump of the relevant process (using Kudu process explorer), and open it in windbg to determine what it's doing.

Comment: See my updated answer: it appears to be vnet related.